# Celery Task Signals, Headers not accessible in signals.task_prerun

Tags: python-3.x, django, asynchronous, celery, celery-4

I am trying to change the behaviour of celery tasks by defining `before_task_publish` and `task_prerun` handler, requirement is, i need pass certain data between the tasks.

I am trying to modify the headers of [before_task_publish](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/v4.4.7/userguide/signals.html#before-task-publish) and trying to access the same in `task_prerun` using `task.request.headers`, but `headers` are blank.

My approach is:

```
from celery_setup import celery_app
from celery import Celery, signals


@signals.before_task_publish.connect
def before_task_publish_handler(sender=None, body=None, headers=None, **kwargs):
    headers['shared_data'] = "Data to share"


@celery_app.task
def my_task(arg):
    print("Task running:", arg)

@signals.task_prerun.connect
def task_prerun_handler(task_id=None, task=None, **kwargs):
    shared_data = task.request.headers.get('shared_data')
    if shared_data:
        print("Shared data in task_prerun:", shared_data)

# Calling the task
my_task.apply_async(args=("Hello, Celery!",), headers={})
```

i am using celery 4.4.4 with Python3.7

I have try this approach, i am expecting to share the data among signals.